# Send notification when ALL TFS 2008 check-ins are made

Tags: branching-and-merging

I know that tfs 2008 can send notification when a check in is made, but in some cases that check in of code won't be the complete fix to a bug, rather it may be a series of changesets. So, is there a way to send a notification through TFS when all changesets to a specific bug is are submitted?

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
nino11

Answer (score 1):

You can configure notifications on check-ins or work item changes - you may wish to perform a notification based on bugs that are marked as resolved and have a changeset associated with it.  These advanced notifications can be configured using the Alert Editor in the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBD14EEA-781F-45A1-8C46-9F6BA2F68BF0&displaylang=en).

Comment: **thanks** for your response. I found out that we do have power tools so i'll explore the alert editor options. Thanks